# Для действий требуется уникальная комбинация метода/пути для Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, swagger, openapi

Пытаюсь сделать клиент-серверное приложение.
Создал два HttpPost, но он ругается на, как я понял, одинаковые пути.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "POST User" for actions - DeliveryApp.Controllers.UserController.Authentication (DeliveryApp),DeliveryApp.Controllers.UserController.Registration (DeliveryApp). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "POST User" for actions - DeliveryApp.Controllers.UserController.Authentication (DeliveryApp),DeliveryApp.Controllers.UserController.Registration (DeliveryApp). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(string documentName, string host, string basePath)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "POST User" for actions - DeliveryApp.Controllers.UserController.Authentication (DeliveryApp),DeliveryApp.Controllers.UserController.Registration (DeliveryApp). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Вот мой код:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DeliveryApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;

        public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "Authentication")]
        [Route("api/[controller]/Authentication")]
        public User Authentication(string login, string password)
        {
            return new User(login, password);
        }
        [HttpPost(Name = "Registration")]
        [Route("api/[controller]/Registration")]
        public bool Registration(string lastName, string firstName, string patronymic, string phoneNumber, string address, string login, string password, Role role = Role.User)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Не очень понимаю, как правильно обойти ошибку.
В голове только - создать два контроллера, хотя, наверное, это не совсем так, как стоило бы сделать.
Хотел бы узнать, как исправить данную проблему элегантно?
Спасибо. :)

Comment: выкладывайте ошибку и исходный код текстом, а не картинкой. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Решила проблему следующие записи:

```
[HttpPost("~/Authentication")]
[HttpPost("~/Registration")]
```

Их нужно написать перед методами класса.

Всем удачи в написании кода! :)